# ASP.net YesorNo PopUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, button

I am confused how to get a yesorno pop up happen at the time I want it to.

On my asp.net web page I have a textbox and a button. When user clicks the button, a calculation occurs. Calculation: sessionValue - whatever is in the text box at that time of the click. If the calculation meets a condition then a yes or no popup box should appear.

Button click logic:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sessionValue = (int)Session["MainValue"];
            int textBoxValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

            int finalValue = sessionValue - textBoxValue;

            if(finalValue < 0)
            {
                //Do a pop up box with yes or no.

                //if yes then do something 

            }
        }
```

I have researched the web and found that you can use the onClientClick properties of the button control to initialise a script that will pop up the box. However, popup box appears when I click the button. It should only appear if the calculation meets the criteria above.

Also the website will be loaded onto a server in the end. MsgBox will not work when user access the website as it's on a server.

Thanks

Comment: what pop up are you trying to get? An alert in javascript?

Comment: A simple yes or no pop up but it needs to occur inside the button click code event(method) not when the user clicks it.

Comment: The button click event happens on the server, so you can't pop anything on the client  directly from there. What you can do is pass something back to the client to tell it to run some JavaScript.

Comment: Is it possible to call scripts inside my button click method?